# Objects that generalizes Universal enveloping/Clifford/Weil algebra and correspondence to algebraic geometry.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, category-theory, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

There are evident similarities between Clifford, Weil and Universal Enveloping algebras. Each may be defined directly as a quotient of the tensor algebra $T(V)$ divided by an ideal generated by some algebraic relations and for each of those there is an alternative definition given by universal property.

Are these algebras generalize to some more general objects (algebraic or categorical ones) and were they been studied? As a side note, these types of algebras resembles coordinate rings on algebraic varieties. Did anyone compared those categories in any way?

Comment: The wikipedia article on Clifford algebras says "More precisely, Clifford algebras may be thought of as quantizations (cf. quantum group) of the exterior algebra, in the same way that the Weyl algebra is a quantization of the symmetric algebra.". The universal enveloping algebra is essentially a "free functor", so I mean a left adjoint to a forgetful functor, given a Lie algebra we construct the universal associative algebra.